# Issue reading reading json tag in php

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I am sending the following json to the server

```
{
"username":"abc@abc.com"    ,
"password":"abc@123","access_key": "api_key",
    "brands": [
        {  "brandname": "Lee","xcoord": "1345",
            "ycoord": "2345","color": {"colorId":8, "rvalue": "234",
                "gvalue": "213","bvalue": "233" }
        },
        {   "brandname": "Pepe","xcoord": "432",
            "ycoord": "4210","color": {"colorId":5, "rvalue": "234",
                "gvalue": "213","bvalue": "233"}
        }
    ],
    "description": "free text",
    "ocassion": 1, // an ocassion id goes here.
    "other_tags": ["other1","other2"],
    "upload_platform":"android|iOS|web"
}
```

When i try to read a specific object color, which resides brands array object as below I am unable to do so and the echo fails, printing nothing. I have never written php, its so easy in java to just use gson and define models that would fill every model up.

```
$userData = urldecode ( $_POST['form'] );
$json = json_decode ( $userData );
$brandTagsArr = $json->brands;

foreach ($brandTagsArr as $brandTag){
                $brandName = $brandTag->brandName; // need to fetch the name and associate brand tag id
                $xCoord = $brandTag->xcoord; // 
                $yCoord = $brandTag->ycoord;
                $this->rest_image_upload_model->insertBrandTags($imageId, $brandName, $xCoord, $yCoord);
                // insert colors
                echo  "insert brand tags <br>";
                $color = $brandTag['color']; // returns nothing FAILS
                $color = $brandTag->color; // returns nothing FAILS
                echo "color id" . $color['colorId'];
                $this->rest_image_upload_model->insertColorTag($imageId, $color['colorId'],$color['rValue'], $color['gValue'], $color['bValue']);
                echo "insert color tags<br>";
                // end inserting colors
            }
```

Comment: does brandtag return anything? try var_dump()

Comment: Can you talk about how you data is POSTed?  Specifically what Content-Type header does the client send?

Comment: @khuderm, yes brandtag has other stuff in the first level association so xcoord and ycoords are present.

Comment: @Mike the data is POSTed as multipart formdata through a rest client for now.

Comment: try with `$json = json_decode ( $userData, true );` what makes a multi level associative array. Make var_dump of this top level array to validate existance of color key.

Comment: Is there a reason why color object will not be present while all other associations are?? I will try this in the morning my PC just died on me

Comment: Not sure why only color wouldn't be there. Try Skamielina's answer. It will turn everything into an array. At least that way, you don't have to use mixed objects and arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the tag name for colors is rvalue,gvalue and bvalue, but you are using as rValue,gValue and bValue. I think thats the issue in your code.

```
    $imageId = 1;
    $a["username"] = "abc@abc.com";
    $a["password"] = "abc@123";
    $a["access_key"] = "api_key";
    $a["description"] = "free text";
    $a["ocassion"] = "1";
    $a["brands"][0]["brandName"] = "Lee";
    $a["brands"][0]["xcoord"] = "1345";
    $a["brands"][0]["ycoord"] = "2345";
    $a["brands"][0]["color"]["colorId"] = "8";
    $a["brands"][0]["color"]["rvalue"] = "234";
    $a["brands"][0]["color"]["gvalue"] = "213";
    $a["brands"][0]["color"]["bvalue"] = "432";
    $a["brands"][1]["brandName"] = "Lee";
    $a["brands"][1]["xcoord"] = "1345";
    $a["brands"][1]["ycoord"] = "2345";
    $a["brands"][1]["color"]["colorId"] = "8";
    $a["brands"][1]["color"]["rvalue"] = "234";
    $a["brands"][1]["color"]["gvalue"] = "213";
    $a["brands"][1]["color"]["bvalue"] = "432";

    $json = json_decode(json_encode($a));
    $brandTagsArr = $json->brands;

    foreach ($brandTagsArr as $brandTag) {
//            print_r($brandTag->color);exit;
            $brandName = $brandTag->brandName; // need to fetch the name and associate brand tag id
            $xCoord = $brandTag->xcoord; // 
            $yCoord = $brandTag->ycoord;
//            $this->rest_image_upload_model->insertBrandTags($imageId, $brandName, $xCoord, $yCoord);
             echo $imageId."===>".$brandName."===>".$xCoord."===>".$yCoord."<br>";
        // insert colors
        echo "insert brand tags <br>";
//            $color = $brandTag['color']; // returns nothing FAILS
            $color = $brandTag->color; // returns nothing FAILS

            echo "color id =>" . $color->colorId;
            echo $imageId."===>".$color->colorId."===>".$color->rvalue."===>".$color->gvalue."===>".$color->bvalue."<br>";
            echo "insert color tags<br>";
            // end inserting colors
        }
```

For your convenience i ve created an array encoded and decoded there only.Hope it helps.

Comment: Let me try this in the evening. I dont have access to this piece of code as of now

Comment: Thanks niranjan the way I was accessing colorId was wrong, Also +1 for saving me the debug time on rValue :)