# Json output format

Tags: php, json

I want to display this json format through php....

```
xyz({
    "something": "something",
    "something": "link",
    "something": "",
    "something": "something",
    "something": "link",
    "items": [
   {
        "something": "something",
        "something": "link",
        "something": {  "m":"link"   },
        "something": "something",
        "something": " <p>something<\/p> ",
        "something": "something",
        "something": "something",
        "something": "something",
        "something": "something"
   },
   {
        "something": "something",
        "something": "link",
        "something": {    "m":"link"   },
        "something": "something",
        "something": " <p>something<\/p> ",
        "something": "something",
        "something": "something",
        "something": "something",
        "something": "something"
   },

    ]
})
```

Comment: good for you, now go write some code...

Comment: you mean you want to traverse the array in php??

Comment: yes @Niranjan want to traverse the array in php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106127/issue-reading-reading-json-tag-in-php/32110348#32110348 check that ,

Comment: Your title is meaningless, and the question is not very descript.

Comment: Give us an example result/output that you're looking for - and demonstrate what things you've already tried.

Comment: I think you should have a look:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054033/pretty-printing-json-with-php/31924211#31924211

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help you:

```
print(json_encode($yourarray));
```

Answer (score 3):

In that case you should use JSON encode:

```
print(json_encode($xyz));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code:

```
    <?php
    $arr = ['1','2']; //Your array
    header('Content-Type: application/json'); //See my explanation
    echo json_encode($arr);
    ?>
```

Although it might not be required for other cases, if you are trying to create an API-like format which seems to me that you are, you need to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` as well so that receiving party gets the correct format.